# xcode project several errors when i try to compile

Tags: ios, xcode

I am new to iphone programming. I have this code (snippet) from a .m file. When I try to        the xcode project I get several errors which I do not understand.

```
-(BOOL)setUp:(BOOL)startImmediate
{
[self saveDownloadInfo];
if (startImmediate)
{
    bar = [UIDownloadBar initWithProgressBarFrame:CGRectMake(0, 17.0, 50, 11.0)
                                delegate:self];

    [bar setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
    [bar beginDownloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self FileUrl]] timeout:600 fileName:[self     FileTitle]];
}
else
{
    bar = [UIDownloadBar initWithProgressBarFrame:CGRectMake(140.0, 36.0, 130.0, 11.0)
                                                 delegate:self];

    [bar setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];

    [bar beginDownloadWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self FileUrl]] timeout:600 fileName:[self FileTitle]];
}
if ([self.orgYTLink length] >0)  bar.orgYTLink = self.orgYTLink;
return YES;
}

-(void)setUpWithPausedDownload:(long long)expectedBytes ReceivedBytes:(float)bytesReceived
{
bar = [UIDownloadBar initWithProgressBarFrame:CGRectMake(140.0, 36, 130.0, 11.0)
                                             delegate:self];

[bar setProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
bar.expectedBytes = expectedBytes;
bar.bytesReceived = bytesReceived;
if (expectedBytes >0) // The download was indeed paused rather than just queued in which case it should have been 0
{
    [bar forceStop];
    // Read the contents of file into the receivedData
//      bar.receivedData = [self loadQueuedOrPausedItemContents];
    bar.progress = ((bytesReceived/(float)expectedBytes)*100)/100;
}
bar.orgYTLink = self.orgYTLink;
}
```

error reports:
[image]

Any idea why it give me this errors?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like you haven't imported `UIKit`.

Comment: Add `@import UIKit;` at the top of the file.

Comment: Hello, I´ve still some issue´s. When I add @import UIKit; I become an error: Use of '@import' when modules are disabled. and when I add #import <UIKit>, xCode tell me the error 'UIKit' file not found. what can I do?